# What is use of self in jquery/ javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript they are using like:

- `var self=this;`
- `var jquery_element= $(html_element);`
- `self.jquery_element=jquery_elemnet`

Why do we use these in javascript. I got this code from [OpenStack horizon](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/horizon/static/horizon/js/horizon.d3linechart.js#L201-207)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var self=this;` is useful for when you have nested functions and `this` can become ambiguous (in case you dont know [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a javascript keyword). `self` can be used to still change the `this` that now reffers to the `this` from the inner function.

`var jquery_element= $(html_element);` just provides a easy way to reference the jQuery element without having to constantly recreate it (also provides performance benefit for instance explained [here](http://ttmm.io/tech/selector-caching-jquery/)).

`self.jquery_element = jquery_element` appears to be specific to that code and I'm not quite sure what it does.

Comment: Good call. I personally go for `var $this = $(this);` (jQuery) and `var that = this` (JS).

Answer (score 6):

It is for visibility in other scope, for using `this` from one scope, within other scope. **Edit.**

```
 var parentFunction = function(){
       this.msg = "hello world";
       var parentScopeSelf = this;
       var innerFunction = function(){
            var innerFunctionScopeSelf = this;
            console.log(this.msg);// undefined (because this now is   innerFunction scope, and does not have property msg)
            console.log(innerFunctionScopeSelf.msg);// undefined (because innerFunctionScopeSelf is "this" from  innerFunction scope, and does not have property msg)
            console.log(parentScopeSelf.msg);// hello world (because parentScopeSelf is "this" from parentFunction scope)
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, why this.msg is undefined but parentScopeSelf.msg is defined ..

Comment: this.msg is undefined because the "this" is from the scope of the inside function and inside the function there is no declared "this.msg". parentScopeSelf.msg is defined because in the outer function there is "this.msg" declared and then "this" was assigned to parentScopeSelf, and even if you change the scope to the inside function parentScopeSelf is still going to be the same, so it will still have a ".msg" from the outer scope

Answer (score 4):

To answer your direct question, `this` is a javascript **keyword**, and its value will change depending on its location. By writing its value to a regular variable like `self`, you are preserving the value wherever `self` is in scope, even if `this` itself has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `this` to another variable is useful when you have nested functions. For instance:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#myInput').on('keyup', function() {
        var $this = $(this); // assign the jQuery's element to $this
        $('div.errors').each(function() {
            console.log($(this)); // outputs jQuery's object div.errors
            console.log($this); // the input is still available in the nested function
        });
    });
});
```

As a recommendation, if a variable stores a `jQuery` element, please prepend it with `$`. Therefore, it should be

```
var $jquery_element = $(html_element);
```

Answer (score 1):

`var jquery_element= $(html_element);`

is to make the html element be a jquery object that can be use with all the method of jquery.

`html_element.fadeOut();` <-- will not work

`$(html_element).fadeOut();` <-- will work